# minecraft world illumination bug

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I created a [modpack](http://technicpack.net/modpack/tfc-pack.745704) and when I enter any GUI (the inventory for example) and get out of it, the world illumination is darker than before and starts to increase brightness slowly.

Mods included:

Terrafirmacraft,
Dynamic Lights,
FastCraft,
Item Physics,
Map Writer,
NEI,
TFC NEI Plugin,
Optifine,
Waila,
Streams,
Finger in the wind,
Shader mod,
Inventory Tweaks,
Sound Filters Mod,

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Created crash-report like Christopher Angelo requested:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I just don't know what went wrong :(

Time: 11/7/15 4:42 PM
Description: Manually triggered debug crash

java.lang.Throwable
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71407_l(Minecraft.java:1759)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71411_J(Minecraft.java:973)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:898)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.WorldClient.func_72914_a(WorldClient.java:373)

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: MpServer
    All players: 1 total; [EntityClientPlayerMP['TuniGamer'/14, l='MpServer', x=7351.24, y=145.62, z=-8216.35]]
    Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 462, 471
    Level seed: -8468897964365267722
    Level generator: ID 00 - TFCDefault, ver 0. Features enabled: false
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: World: (7360,146,-8848), Chunk: (at 0,9,0 in 460,-553; contains blocks 7360,0,-8848 to 7375,255,-8833), Region: (14,-18; contains chunks 448,-576 to 479,-545, blocks 7168,0,-9216 to 7679,255,-8705)
    Level time: 611720 game time, 611720 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: survival (ID 0). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
    Forced entities: 23 total; [EntityClientPlayerMP['TuniGamer'/14, l='MpServer', x=7351.24, y=145.62, z=-8216.35], EntityPigTFC['Pig'/18, l='MpServer', x=7215.50, y=145.00, z=-8137.50], EntityPigTFC['Pig'/19, l='MpServer', x=7219.50, y=155.00, z=-8145.50], EntityPigTFC['Pig'/22, l='MpServer', x=7216.50, y=146.00, z=-8141.50], EntitySquidTFC['Squid'/31, l='MpServer', x=7317.56, y=134.34, z=-8275.38], EntitySquidTFC['Squid'/32, l='MpServer', x=7325.06, y=133.19, z=-8271.38], EntitySquidTFC['Squid'/33, l='MpServer', x=7325.84, y=133.00, z=-8273.66], EntitySquidTFC['Squid'/36, l='MpServer', x=7326.97, y=135.31, z=-8272.75], EntityItem['item.item.LooseRock.Claystone'/37, l='MpServer', x=7330.31, y=148.13, z=-8164.50], EntityItem['item.item.LooseRock.Claystone'/38, l='MpServer', x=7328.72, y=148.13, z=-8162.50], EntityPheasantTFC['Pheasant'/40, l='MpServer', x=7357.59, y=145.00, z=-8331.63], EntityPheasantTFC['Pheasant'/41, l='MpServer', x=7352.53, y=145.00, z=-8328.22], EntityHorseTFC['Horse'/42, l='MpServer', x=7368.28, y=145.00, z=-8290.28], EntityHorseTFC['Horse'/43, l='MpServer', x=7366.56, y=145.00, z=-8288.84], EntityItem['item.item.Seeds Wheat'/44, l='MpServer', x=7373.75, y=144.13, z=-8184.16], EntityBat['Bat'/45, l='MpServer', x=7382.50, y=55.10, z=-8144.50], EntityBat['Bat'/46, l='MpServer', x=7384.66, y=55.00, z=-8145.41], EntityBat['Bat'/47, l='MpServer', x=7383.75, y=55.00, z=-8147.44], EntityPigTFC['Pig'/48, l='MpServer', x=7405.72, y=144.00, z=-8342.72], EntityPigTFC['Pig'/49, l='MpServer', x=7394.84, y=144.00, z=-8345.78], EntityCowTFC['Cow'/53, l='MpServer', x=7470.38, y=144.00, z=-8113.06], EntityCowTFC['Cow'/54, l='MpServer', x=7470.41, y=144.00, z=-8114.72], EntityCowTFC['Cow'/55, l='MpServer', x=7471.59, y=144.00, z=-8114.53]]
    Retry entities: 0 total; []
    Server brand: fml,forge
    Server type: Integrated singleplayer server
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.WorldClient.func_72914_a(WorldClient.java:373)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71396_d(Minecraft.java:2444)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:919)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
    Operating System: Windows 8.1 (amd64) version 6.3
    Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 2898969376 bytes (2764 MB) / 3509583872 bytes (3347 MB) up to 4294967296 bytes (4096 MB)
    JVM Flags: 4 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx4096m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=4
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP v9.05 FML v7.10.99.99 Minecraft Forge 10.13.4.1448 Optifine OptiFine_1.7.10_HD_C1 28 mods loaded, 28 mods active
    States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored
    UCHIJAAAA   mcp{9.05} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   FML{7.10.99.99} [Forge Mod Loader] (modpack.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   Forge{10.13.4.1448} [Minecraft Forge] (modpack.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   tfc_coremod{0.79.25} [TFC[coremod]] (minecraft.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   CodeChickenCore{1.0.4.29} [CodeChicken Core] (minecraft.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   itemphysic{1.1.2} [ItemPhysic] (minecraft.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   MobiusCore{1.2.3} [MobiusCore] (minecraft.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   NotEnoughItems{1.0.3.74} [Not Enough Items] (NotEnoughItems-1.7.10-1.0.3.74-universal.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   terrafirmacraft{0.79.25} [TerraFirmaCraft] ([1.7.10]TerraFirmaCraft-0.79.25.845.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   creativecore{1.2.0} [CreativeCore] (CreativeCore v1.2.2 mc1.7.10.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   DynamicLights{1.3.8} [Dynamic Lights] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   DynamicLights_onFire{1.0.4} [Dynamic Lights Burning Entity Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   DynamicLights_creepers{1.0.4} [Dynamic Lights Creeper Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   DynamicLights_dropItems{1.0.8} [Dynamic Lights EntityItem Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   DynamicLights_entityClasses{1.0.1} [Dynamic Lights Entity Light Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   DynamicLights_mobEquipment{1.0.8} [Dynamic Lights Mob Equipment Light Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   DynamicLights_flameArrows{1.0.0} [Dynamic Lights Fiery Arrows Light Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   DynamicLights_floodLights{1.0.2} [Dynamic Lights Flood Light] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   DynamicLights_otherPlayers{1.0.8} [Dynamic Lights OtherPlayers Light Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   DynamicLights_thePlayer{1.1.4} [Dynamic Lights Player Light Module] (DynamicLights-1.7.10.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   farseek{1.0.10} [Farseek] (Farseek-1.0.10.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   FastCraft{1.21} [FastCraft] (fastcraft-1.21.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   inventorytweaks{1.58-147-645ca10} [Inventory Tweaks] (InventoryTweaks-1.58-147.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   MapWriter{2.1.2} [MapWriter] (MapWriter-Mod-1.7.10.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   soundfilters{0.8_for_1.7.X} [Sound Filters] (SoundFilters-0.8_for_1.7.X.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   streams{0.1.6} [Streams] (Streams-0.1.6.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   TerraFirmaCraftNEIplugin{1.4.0.19} [TerraFirmaCraftNEIplugin] (TerraFirmaCraftNEIplugin-1.7.10-1.4.0.19.jar) 
    UCHIJAAAA   Waila{1.5.5} [Waila] (Waila-1.5.5_1.7.10.jar) 
    GL info: ' Vendor: 'NVIDIA Corporation' Version: '4.5.0 NVIDIA 353.62' Renderer: 'GeForce GT 635/PCIe/SSE2'
    Launched Version: 1.7.10-Forge10.13.4.1448-1.7.10
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: GeForce GT 635/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.5.0 NVIDIA 353.62, NVIDIA Corporation
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Anisotropic filtering is supported and maximum anisotropy is 16.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.

    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: [[79.8] Faithful TFC.zip]
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about modded minecraft support

Comment: @imulsion Modded minecraft support is on topic. Modded minecraft **crash** support is not.

Comment: Create a crash log by holding F3+C for 10 seconds and include it in your question.

Comment: I was testing around and disabling and enabling mods, it turns out that the problem solved itself. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Think this should be closed as this is actually a graphics problem over a gaming question

Comment: Anyway heres the crash log

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we cannot offer support for issues with mods related to crash logs.

Comment: @r3tr0t3hPeNgU1NoFd00m The game did *not* crash, that log is provided because someone from the comments asked for it.

Comment: @r3tr0t3hPeNgU1NoFd00m Despite the 'crash log', which was provided at the request of a comment, Minecraft was launching and not crashing (or, at least, the issue at hand was not related to crashing).

Comment: I think it is a bug from Terrafirmacraft mod. Now it happens only when you open the knapping interface.